# Android 7.0 javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: when trying to get a website content from url

Tags: java, android, ssl

I'm building App on android 7.0 api level 24. I try to connect to a website and download its content using Jsoup library

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(link).get();
```

And I get following error:
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: SSL handshake aborted: ssl=0xda9ba6c0: I/O error during system call, Connection reset by peer

```
01-06 18:01:42.137 2396-4760/com.example.sonia.asystentgotowania W/System.err: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: SSL handshake aborted: ssl=0xda9ba6c0: I/O error during system call, Connection reset by peer
01-06 18:01:42.141 2396-4760/com.example.sonia.asystentgotowania W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native Method)
01-06 18:01:42.141 2396-4760/com.example.sonia.asystentgotowania W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:364)
01-06 18:01:42.141 2396-4760/com.example.sonia.asystentgotowania W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connectTls(Connection.java:1510)
01-06 18:01:42.141 2396-4760/com.example.sonia.asystentgotowania W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connectSocket(Connection.java:1458)
01-06 18:01:42.141 2396-4760/com.example.sonia.asystentgotowania W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java:1413)
01-06 18:01:42.141 2396-4760/com.example.sonia.asystentgotowania W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connectAndSetOwner(Connection.java:1700)
01-06 18:01:42.141 2396-4760/com.example.sonia.asystentgotowania W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.OkHttpClient$1.connectAndSetOwner(OkHttpClient.java:133)
01-06 18:01:42.141 2396-4760/com.example.sonia.asystentgotowania W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:466)
01-06 18:01:42.141 2396-4760/com.example.sonia.asystentgotowania W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:371)
01-06 18:01:42.141 2396-4760/com.example.sonia.asystentgotowania W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:503)
01-06 18:01:42.141 2396-4760/com.example.sonia.asystentgotowania W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:130)
01-06 18:01:42.141 2396-4760/com.example.sonia.asystentgotowania W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.connect(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:89)
01-06 18:01:42.141 2396-4760/com.example.sonia.asystentgotowania W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java)
01-06 18:01:42.142 2396-4760/com.example.sonia.asystentgotowania W/System.err:     at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:730)
01-06 18:01:42.142 2396-4760/com.example.sonia.asystentgotowania W/System.err:     at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:706)
01-06 18:01:42.142 2396-4760/com.example.sonia.asystentgotowania W/System.err:     at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.execute(HttpConnection.java:299)
01-06 18:01:42.142 2396-4760/com.example.sonia.asystentgotowania W/System.err:     at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.get(HttpConnection.java:288)
01-06 18:01:42.142 2396-4760/com.example.sonia.asystentgotowania W/System.err:     at com.example.sonia.asystentgotowania.onerecipe.recipefromlink.RecipeFromLink.getWebsiteContent(RecipeFromLink.java:84)
01-06 18:01:42.142 2396-4760/com.example.sonia.asystentgotowania W/System.err:     at com.example.sonia.asystentgotowania.onerecipe.recipefromlink.RecipeFromLink.<init>(RecipeFromLink.java:44)
01-06 18:01:42.142 2396-4760/com.example.sonia.asystentgotowania W/System.err:     at com.example.sonia.asystentgotowania.onerecipe.RecipeActivity.getRecipeFormLink(RecipeActivity.java:131)
01-06 18:01:42.142 2396-4760/com.example.sonia.asystentgotowania W/System.err:     at com.example.sonia.asystentgotowania.onerecipe.RecipeActivity.access$100(RecipeActivity.java:27)
01-06 18:01:42.142 2396-4760/com.example.sonia.asystentgotowania W/System.err:     at com.example.sonia.asystentgotowania.onerecipe.RecipeActivity$3.run(RecipeActivity.java:102)
01-06 18:01:42.142 2396-4760/com.example.sonia.asystentgotowania W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:762)
01-06 18:01:42.142 2396-4760/com.example.sonia.asystentgotowania W/System.err:  Suppressed: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Handshake failed
01-06 18:01:42.142 2396-4760/com.example.sonia.asystentgotowania W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:444)
01-06 18:01:42.142 2396-4760/com.example.sonia.asystentgotowania W/System.err:      ... 21 more
01-06 18:01:42.143 2396-4760/com.example.sonia.asystentgotowania W/System.err:      Suppressed: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Handshake failed
01-06 18:01:42.143 2396-4760/com.example.sonia.asystentgotowania W/System.err:          ... 22 more
01-06 18:01:42.143 2396-4760/com.example.sonia.asystentgotowania W/System.err:      Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: SSL handshake terminated: ssl=0xda9ba6c0: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error
01-06 18:01:42.143 2396-4760/com.example.sonia.asystentgotowania W/System.err: error:10000410:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:SSLV3_ALERT_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE (external/boringssl/src/ssl/s3_pkt.c:641 0xd677d440:0x00000001)
01-06 18:01:42.143 2396-4760/com.example.sonia.asystentgotowania W/System.err: error:1000009a:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:HANDSHAKE_FAILURE_ON_CLIENT_HELLO (external/boringssl/src/ssl/s3_clnt.c:800 0xdac71a9f:0x00000000)
01-06 18:01:42.143 2396-4760/com.example.sonia.asystentgotowania W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native Method)
01-06 18:01:42.143 2396-4760/com.example.sonia.asystentgotowania W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:364)
01-06 18:01:42.143 2396-4760/com.example.sonia.asystentgotowania W/System.err:          ... 21 more
01-06 18:01:42.143 2396-4760/com.example.sonia.asystentgotowania W/System.err:  Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: SSL handshake terminated: ssl=0xda9ba6c0: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error
01-06 18:01:42.143 2396-4760/com.example.sonia.asystentgotowania W/System.err: error:1000043e:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:TLSV1_ALERT_INAPPROPRIATE_FALLBACK (external/boringssl/src/ssl/s3_pkt.c:641 0xd677d440:0x00000001)
01-06 18:01:42.143 2396-4760/com.example.sonia.asystentgotowania W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native Method)
01-06 18:01:42.143 2396-4760/com.example.sonia.asystentgotowania W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:364)
01-06 18:01:42.143 2396-4760/com.example.sonia.asystentgotowania W/System.err:      ... 21 more
```

What I've tried:
I added a network_security_config.xml in res/xml/

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <base-config>
        <trust-anchors>
            <certificates src="@raw/extracas"/>
            <certificates src="system"/>
        </trust-anchors>
    </base-config>
</network-security-config>
```

and

```
android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
```

to manifest

But I still get the same error. There are many similar questions, but none of them has an answer, which works.

I can enter this website via chrome and whole code was working in eclipse on desktop, so it must be some android issue.

Comment: remove s from https =>use http in your link, and then try again

Comment: Does this happen with every https site you access (i.e. try Google, Twitter, Facebook...). Or does it happen only with selected sites. In this case - what is the URL which causes the problem?